# How do I globally load Rmetric Financial calendars into `golem` at the startup?

Tags: r, shiny, golem, bizdays

**Question:**

What are the best practices to go about setting a "global" financial calendar using `load_rmetrics_calenders()`,
ie a singular run of a function in golem?

**Background:**

This question is asked prior to finding a possible solution. I am using a function that I made which uses the `{bizdays}` package to determine certain financial dates. I need to use the function `load_rmetrics_calenders()` to initiate/set the calenders for a subsequent call in `bizdayz::adjust.previous(..., cal = "Rmetrics/NYSE)`. I understand I could also use a globl setting to set the calneder but that has given me issues in the past.

I would like the to run `load_rmetrics_calenders()` once at the beginning of a golem instance -- rather than having to call the function directly in the function, which slows it down a fair bit.

**Reprex:**

```
my_function<- function(stock = NULL, from = NULL, to = NULL, ...){
    # Set Biz Calender 
 
    # bizdays::load_rmetrics_calendars(year = c(1950:2030), financial = TRUE)

    # DEFENSIVES ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Assign `to` --> yesterdays close, will reset when close data comes in, 12am
    to <- bizdays::adjust.previous(Sys.Date() - 1, cal = "Rmetrics/NYSE")
```

I would like to omit setting the calendar every time I call this function, or its called in the `golemApp` instance while running online.

**Possible answers:**

- Execute `load_rmetrics_calenders()` within `golem::runApp()` --> once when launched
- Execute `load_rmetrics_calenders()` within the server of a `golem` module that acts as a homepage for the website/app
- Embed the calendar into settings? --> not aware of a working solution

**#1:** Current implementation

```
# Just running the function within the `runApp()`

run_app <- function(
  onStart = NULL,
  options = list(),
  enableBookmarking = NULL,
  ...
) {

  #Configure financial calender
  golem::cat_dev("Loading NYSE calender from Quantlib \n")
  bizdays::load_quantlib_calendars(ql_calendars = "UnitedStates/NYSE", from = "1950-01-01", to = "2030-01-01")
  golem::cat_dev("Done loading calender. \n")

  # Configure global polished settings
  polished_config()

  reactlog::reactlog_enable()

  with_golem_options(
    app = brochureApp(
      # Putting the resources here
      golem_add_external_resources(),
      # Add pages
      welcomePage(),
      # login(),
      dashboard(),
      # logout(),
      terms(),
      onStart = onStart,
      options = options,
      enableBookmarking = enableBookmarking,
      wrapped = shiny::tagList
    ),
    golem_opts = list(...)
  )
}
```

**#2:** Writing it in a script to run instead of calling `runApp()` ie from Docker

```
# .R file to be called instead of running run_app() explicitly 

  #Configure financial calender
  golem::cat_dev("Loading NYSE calender from Quantlib \n")
  bizdays::load_quantlib_calendars(ql_calendars = "UnitedStates/NYSE", from = "1950-01-01", to = "2030-01-01")
  golem::cat_dev("Done loading calender. \n")

  # Configure global polished settings
  polished_config(...)

  reactlog::reactlog_enable()

# Run app with the calendar loaded
run_app()
```

Comment: Note that the Rmetrics code has been stale for a few years meaning that calendar rules update are missing (example: Juneteenth added this year).  My [qlcal package on CRAN](https://cloud.r-project.org/package=qlcal) offers a current and updated alternative.

Comment: thank you @DirkEddelbuettel, will I have to use a dependency on `quantlib`? I had issues recently with `quantLib.so` and using `load_quantlib_calenders()` in a dockerfile, which is why I switched to `Rmetric`

Comment: No, please read up more carefully on qlcal which _extracts_ the calendaring code and is self-contained.  If that is worded clearly enough please consider opening an issue with proposed improvements.

Comment: Yes, i understand how `{qlcal}` pulls just the calendaring out, thank you! I wasn't able to find an integration with `{bizdays}` however. Is the only way forward with `{qlcal}` to change `bizdays::adjust.previous(Sys.Date() - 1, cal = "Rmetrics/NYSE")` into `qlcal` logic with `advanceDate`? or can i load a `qlcal` calender into the `bizdays` function? If so, how would I use `setCalender` to do so? @DirkEddelbuettel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the function before the `run_app()` function is launched and pass the result as an argument to the `run_app()` fun.

For example: https://github.com/inrae/diades.atlas/blob/main/app.R#L30, here, I build a series of elements and they are passed to run_app(), so it's run less often (here, every time a new app is launched in RStudio Connect).

You can also set at the top of your server if you want the function to be launched at every shiny session (but I suppose this is not exactly what you want).

So, it depends of your deployment logic:

- If you're deploying a container, you can use (pseudo code here) : `CMD R -e "myapp::run_app(data = mypak:build_stuff())"`. Note that it will depend on the container management service you are using. For example Shiny Proxy will run one container by user, so `build_stuff()` will be called every time a new user comes.
- If you're on RStudio Product, you can use the run_app() method from the linked GitHub code.

If you need to explore the behavior of `{golem}` apps and when things are run, I've got a toy example here https://github.com/ColinFay/golemexamples/tree/master/golemloadorder that will let you know when things are run/loaded.

Cheers,
Colin

Comment: For the first example you gave, passing as an arg to run_app(), [link](https://github.com/inrae/diades.atlas/blob/main/app.R#L30), in the `{brochure}` framework if I understand correctly there is no `app.R` file rather, should I whip a quick script similar to `app.R`, to then call from docker, or embed the script into the `data` arg of runApp? Is there a better ay one way or the other? -- currently I have it just running within `runApp` itself. I'll tinker around w the `golemloadorder` too! see above implementation

Comment: TL;DR -- Is logic #2 from above question better/worse/same as logic in #1?